# Android - Fragment replace not replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to replace fragment and destroy previous.

Here my code :

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction newT = manager.beginTransaction();
newT.replace(R.id.activity_content currentFragment, CE_TAG);
newT.commit();
```

I read this article : http://sapandiwakar.in/replacing-fragments/

I've not put the fragment in back stack, but my fragement are not destroyed !

`onPause()`, `onDestroy()`, `onStop()` are never called.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you know it is not destroyed?

Comment: Because I display a log in the onDestroy method

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Fragment f = new YOurFragment();
```

`fragmentTransaction.remove(f).commit();`

Hope it helps

Comment: you can use the same line inside your onDestroy() metho
but instead of remove(f) you shall call remove(this)

Comment: the onDestroy is never called !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line of code after committing the transaction.

```
getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Check this [executePendingTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29).

If you are replacing a fragment with the same tag, it may cause the issue of overlaping. Also, if your fragment container is a `LinearLayout`, it cannot update after replace (from my experience only).

Comment: when I try this getChildFragmentManager() is not found

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is maintained in memory even after it is no longer visible. If you call it back into existence, `onCreateView` is called and the visual part of the fragment is recreated but the actual object is reused. From the Docs:

> onDestroy() = The final call you receive before your activity is
>   destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing
>   (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily
>   destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can
>   distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

You should consider `onDestroyView` instead, or call `finish` if that suits you better.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html